# Data Query time of unordered_map is not fast enough for my problem

Tags: c++, arrays, dictionary, hashtable, a-star

I'm implementing A* algorithm which requires a faster query of data, the best way I could think of is Hash Tables (unordered_map in cpp) but the computation time is little high(4 micro secs for each query) for my use case.

A*: A* is a Heuristic-based search method to find the optimal solution in a given map. It finds the path by creating and expanding the tree (each node in the tree is a specific location on the map) from start to goal, when a new node is created the algorithm checks whether same node has been created before.

To check the newly created node availability, I'm pushing the all the nodes into a dictionary and querying it when necessary, but as mentioned the query time is higher than what I need for my problem, an alternative approach I tried is by creating a 2D array of booleans (true for occupied and false for unoccupied) with the size of map and querying it directly from the 2d array, but the problem is the memory creation for the array is too high.

Are there any other approaches for faster query?

Comment: `unordered_map` is a good general purpose hash-table, but in some cases another implementation can be much faster (e.g. an order of magnitude).  I suggest you take a look at some recent efforts - e.g. https://probablydance.com/2017/02/26/i-wrote-the-fastest-hashtable/ and https://engineering.fb.com/2019/04/25/developer-tools/f14/ - and try one of the implementations mentioned therein.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response to your help, actually I found another method, but this seems more efficient, thanks :)